# Can't get R.java back in eclipse

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, r.java-file

I have a massive problem, and I can't find a single thread out there that specifies this problem.
I'd been watching Google IO, and the Android Studio was mentioned, I downloaded it, installed it, and opened my project into there, as I wanted to try out some of the new features, Fine and dandy, (on a separate note, I love Android Studio)

It was working before in Eclipse, and I literally changed nothing about my project, I was only looking around at the device preview features and stuff, didn't touch any piece of code what so ever, just having a look at some of the features..
Went back to eclipse, and my generated folder only showed R in, no tree structure of R or anything, just R.java, and R inside it, and everything in my classes were underlined, but it wasn't the R that was, it was the value after it (ie. Cannot find R.*layout*.main) which I thought was really weird, so I cleaned my project, and it disappeared, I now have a project without a generated R.java file.

To note; I changed **nothing** about my project, all my XML files were absolutely fine, i've tried every trick I can find on StackOverFlow and other websites (removing some of the XML's, painstakingly going over my 15 layout files character by character for an hour, removing imports, build paths, etc) and nothing works, and i've been trying to do this for almost 3 hours now.. Does anyone have any experience doing this, or any solution?

Comment: The R class is automatically generated, sometimes is not when you have some package issues, but is not your case

Comment: I had problems 2 after installing Android Studio. Check everything in Java build path in the project properties. Also in projects I didnt even open with Eclipse or Android Studio. I had to re attach some jar's in "Libraries" and change stuff in "Order and Export".

Answer (score 0):

in the Gen section of your project, try to delete the R.java

It should re-generate, I had some issues like that in the past..

Give it go.

Comment: Tried it, didn't help :/

Answer (score 0):

The `R file` may not be generated due to errors in the project.
Check your xml files in `res` folder. Also read `Error log` of the eclipse.
(`Windows -> Show View -> Problems`)

Comment: I checked that, but it showed no errors what-so-ever; I tried re-importing the project, deleting and re-generating classes, etc. Nothing.. Eventually, I just used Android Studio from now on; cannot find the solution :(

Answer (score 0):

The best way is copy R.java from another project and Past it in gen
And then Delete R.java file then the system will recreate R.java back for you..........